# Difference between kovri tunnel types

Tags: kovri, i2p

In [Stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org), there is only 2 types of tunnels : client and server.

Why is there [more types](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/pkg/config/tunnels.conf) in kovri tunnels ?

What is the difference between types `server`  and `http` ? and between `client` and `irc` ?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually speaking, there are still only 2 types of tunnels : client and server.

But the idea is that we can do "better" for a specific application/protocol by leveraging some of its characteristics.

So `http` is a specialization of a `server` tunnel for the [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), and likewise, `irc` is a specialization of a `client` tunnel for the [IRC protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat).

Currently, there is no distinction between `irc` and `client`. There is [this open ticket](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/issues/9) for this task.

AFAICT, [here](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/src/client/tunnel.cc#L245) is the only distinction between `http` and `server` : it looks like it's used to dynamically change the `Host` parameter in the header of an HTTP request.